# How to fix android lag for grid with a lot of elements

Tags: android

So what i have is a RelativeLayout that is a grid with 25x25 elements what i am trying to do is make a crossword puzzle. I use the https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout so i can zoom in and out of the puzzle. The cells are pretty simple they are only a TextView with background a png image that is set in the xml. There is no lag if this stays like this but if i try to use CardView or try to do a elevation of the cell so there is a shadow it starts to lag(interestingly it lags only on a real device not on emulator).

1. So i was wondering am i approaching the problem in a wrong way?
2. Should i just remove the grid and try to draw on the canvas?
3. Is there a way to optimize the shadows so they don't cause lag?
4. Should i cache the background image of the TextView in a bitmap and pass it in the TextView so i maybe get a faster loading (i don't know how this works since the image is loaded in the xml so i assume it uses a cached image)?
5. Should i just use some other way to do the game?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to draw the grid on the canvas and when the user taps the grid, calculate the cell at that location and add a new View (CardView with whatever properties you want) at that point. Your performance will be drastically better but it does require you do do some Math.